# How can I have a cell that when edited publishes it's edit date next to it? In Google Sheets using a Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is what I've got:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var val = range.getValue();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var shift = 1;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, (col+shift));
  
  if (col == 3){
    ss.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss");
  }
  if (val == ""){
    ss.setValue("").setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss");
  }
}
```

This is what is happening:

[image]

[image]

However, when I edit a cell in barcode, it doesn't update the timestamp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==3 && e.value) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```

I presume you wouldn't want to this for all sheets but I could be wrong.

Comment: [Never mind](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6984051?hl=en).

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined (line 2).` FYI, I deleted your comments. So, line 4 if included.

Comment: You cannot run these functions with the event block that come with the trigger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222869/discussion-between-cooper-and-loie-benedicte).

Comment: To test the the code copy the the code into script edtitor and save it.  The goto  Sheet1 column 3 and make an edit